# Xpages browser error

Tags: browser, error-handling, xpages

I have the following error:

```
Error 403

HTTP Web Server: You are forbidden to perform this operation
```

I had this application on local and it worked fine both client and browser. But when I created a copy on our server (I  have access to the server) the application works fine on client, but on web I have the above error. Any ideas?

Thank you,

Florin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sign your database with an id which is allowed to "Sign or run unrestricted methods and operations". This is a setting in Domino Directory Server document Security tab.

Comment: Knut has the solution.  The issue is the person that created or last signed the application does not have the access rights to run it on the server.  Local testing doesn't check for this.  That's one reason why I never develop with the local preview option.