# Xpages Error 403

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino

We are using Domino server and Domino Designer.

We had to learn to build projects using Xpages for developing Web app-s.
After doing a preview in Notes it works flawless, but when we try to do preview in Internet explorer, Google chrome or Mozzila we get

**Error 403, You are forbidden to perform this action.**

Even with all the server rights we get that message.
We tried everything (turning off automatic build, trying to build on a clean nsf), and don't know what are we doing wrong.
Are there setting we need to set up on server, or the way to build application.
Please help we are desperate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xpages browser error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25659928/xpages-browser-error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to sign the database with a Notes id which is allowed to execute XPages.

Paul is right, this is a [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25660136/2065611).