# Xpages dojo.js, xspClientdojo.js not loading ERROR 403

Tags: javascript, dojo, xpages

I am working on a xpages application which is having anonymous access to editor level. As I have build a login authorization for the users which are not notes users, I am using session-scope to hold the session for these users,

Now the problem is on my testing server, Every thing works fine, it is tested the server is with FP8,

On customer side the server is with FP9.

I have an Idea that there is might be some access settings for JavaScript Some in the server setting but the confusion is that the the other javaScript like Jquery , and all other which I have created gets loaded perfectly.

One other difference is that on my testing server the application is working on http. On the customer side it is https.

Cannot guess exactly what is going wrong, in the setting or anything with http/https. The image is the browser console of both the servers.

---

> Customer-side
>
> ---

[image]

---

> Our Testing server

---

[image]

Comment: Hi, is the application signed on the customer side with an appropriate id ?

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25659928/xpages-browser-error).

Comment: Yes @umeli, this application is signed at customer side because we also have another application on the same server of customer which works fine, but the diference is that . The above mentioned database has anonymous access , but the other database which works fine does not has anonymous access. So is there any other things to have a look for anoynous access?

Comment: what kind of access does anonymous have? reader or more ? or only read public access ?

Comment: It has editor access